# Reading/writing to/from a csv file on an ftp server Visual Studio 2010

Tags: vb.net, csv, ftp

I am currently learning reading from and writing to csv files at school for my software development class. I am trying to adapt what we are learning and use it for a personal program i am making and i wish to have this csv file stored on my ftp server so that it can be edited and accessed on all computers the application is running on rather than each computer having a different copy (eg the csv contains personal info and i change my phone number using the program on my laptop i want it to go to a csv on an ftp rather than a csv file stored locally on my computer so that i can go to another computer and log in to the application and have the  new phone number there as well.

This is a sample of the code i have been using for the csv but it does not like the file path

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim Wstream As New StreamWriter("ftp://daves-computers.bugs3.com/InvoiceDatabase/personal_data.csv", True)
        Wstream.Write(txtName + "," + txtPhone)
        Wstream.WriteLine()
        Wstream.Close()
    End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. also yes that is the ftp server and directory that i wish to store the file.
Also i may need to use a username and password to access the file on the ftp server so is there a way to put that in as well?

thanks

Comment: Hi, i don't thik that you can do it :).ftp suppose that your working on the net(Internet/intranet) so in order to perform your task you need to have a copy of your file locally, modify it, and update file remotly.So first of all downloadfiles locally, change the info,re-upload the file.No other way :).All ftp client make all same stuff in same order.Download=>modify=>Re-Upload :)I hope it help you

Comment: thank you but it would be a great effort and would not work as this application will be on many client computers and if they change the information in the csv it will be of great difficulty to them to modify all the information, it would be easier for me to continue to hvave them email information changes in and then i make the changes and send out an update. Is it possible to perhaps use something rather than a csv to achieve what io am looking for? @makemoney2010

Comment: sure you can use a simple database and do it in other way.You can create a simple database access or mssql or mysql, create your own table within with its own fields and then using adonet, linq, or any other preferred type of dataaccess to perform update in realtime with locking table and many other stuff.Let me know if i can help you a little bit more.I will happy to help you.